# Alternative definition of real valued random variable using Cartesian product

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know that $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a real valued random variable if and only if for any Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the set $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$.

However, I would like to prove the alternative definition using using Cartesian product, that is:

$X$ is a real valued random variable, if and only if for any numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ it's true that $$X^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda_1] \times \ldots \times (-\infty,\lambda_n]) \in \mathcal{F}.$$

I realize that proving ''$\Rightarrow$'' is easy: the set $(-\infty,\lambda_1] \times \ldots \times (-\infty,\lambda_n]$ is a Cartesian product and therefore a subset of a family of Borel sets. However, I fail to see how to prove ''$\Leftarrow$''. I' ve seen some proofs of this in the literature for a one-dimensional case and while they're neat and short, I have an inkling I'm missing some deeper underlying concepts in those proofs.

Comment: I suppose it follows from the fact that the Borel algebra is generated by the family $\lbrace (-\infty , \lambda_{1} ]\times \cdots \times (-\infty , \lambda_{n}] \mid \lambda_{1} , \ldots ,\lambda_{n} \in \mathbb{R}\rbrace$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that
$$
\mathcal{A}=\{B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\mid X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}\}.
$$
is a $\sigma$-field. Then since
$$
\{(-\infty,\lambda_1]\times\cdots\times(-\infty,\lambda_n]\mid \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathcal{A}
$$
we automatically get that
$$
\sigma(\{(-\infty,\lambda_1]\times\cdots\times(-\infty,\lambda_n]\mid \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}\})\subseteq\mathcal{A}.
$$
Finally, use that the left-hand side is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to conclude.